# Uncaught TyperError in Chat Application Using Node.js, Vue.js + Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, socket.io

I am getting an uncaught TyperError in this chat application prototype.

HTML file (also contains Vue.js script)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fireside Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Fireside Chat</h1>    
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="messageVar in messages">
        {{ messageVar }} 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form @submit.prevent="sendMessage">
      <input type="text" placeHolder="Message..." v-model:value="message"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = null; 
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: '',
        messages: ''
      },
      methods: {
        sendMessage: function () {
          socket.emit('message', this.message);
          this.message = '';
        }
      },
      created: function () {
        socket = io();
      },
      mounted: function () {
        socket.on('message'), function (message) {
          app.messages.push // context of callback function is different

        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

app.use('/style', express.static(__dirname + '/style'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('message', (msg) => console.log(msg))         // successful
  socket.on('message', (msg) => io.emit('message', msg))  // UNSUCCESSFUL - WHY?
})

// start up http server
http.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000'))
```

I run the code in a development environment using the command
`node serverFileName.js` and test the application at `http://localhost:3000/`

In the server file code I am able to successfully log a message to the console (it shows up in the terminal window where I started the development node server), but when I try to emit the message to the client using socket.io I see this error message on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at  
  Socket../node_modules/component-emitter/index.js.Emitter.emit (index.js:145)
```

The code at the specified line in index.js is this:

```
  if (callbacks) {
    callbacks = callbacks.slice(0);
    for (var i = 0, len = callbacks.length; i < len; ++i) {
      callbacks[i].apply(this, args);
    }
  }
```

Why is this emit function failing?

Comment: How about `socket.on('message', (msg) => {io.emit('message', msg))}`

Comment: since you have already received this message on the line earlier, it is undefined on the second line.

`io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.on('message', (msg) => {console.log(msg); io.emit('message', msg);})
    })`

Comment: @kallosz I think you're right that I should not have used redundant 'socket.on' statements. However when I tried using the code in your comment it resulted in the same error.